# IIS home page is getting loaded instead of sitecore 9.3 Home page

Tags: site-configuration, iis

I am a newbie to Sitecore 9.3.
I have integrated sitecore 9.3 and VS 2017 but i am not able to load the sitecore 9.3 home page, instead  IIS Home page gets loaded up. [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your host entry in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file and also check IIS for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the site with SIA, then below can be the possible solutions:

1. Try running an `iisreset` in Command Prompt as Administrator.
2. Check if you are browsing the site with `https://` at the beginning of the URL.

Answer (score 5):

Sitecore 9+ by default the sites are secure only. Please try with https://sitecoreinstance93sc.dev.local

Couple of things can be verified with these issues:

1. Open IIS and right click on the website
   [image: IIS Configuration]
2. Host Entries open the following file in notepad

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
> you should see an entry for 127.0.0.1  sitecoreinstance93sc.dev.local

3. Check the custom Site definition mostly located in the following path and ensure the hostName attribute
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yoursite\App_Config\Include\SiteDefinition.config

Comment: Browsing the site with https:// solved my issue.thanks